# MKUserTrackingButton - How to get centre map on user's location without zooming out?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I have implemented the MKUserTrackingButton in my map, but the problem is sometimes when it is pressed, it zooms out the map and then it centres on the user's current location. What I want to do is simply centre on the user's location without zooming out.

Is there a way to do that?

Does the MKUserTrackingButton have a property that I can alter so that when it is tapped, it only centres the map instead of zooming out?

Here is my code to add the button:

```
    let Userbutton = MKUserTrackingButton(mapView: mapview)
    Userbutton.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 1, alpha: 0.8).cgColor
    Userbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    Userbutton.layer.borderWidth = 1
    Userbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    Userbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    Userbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    Userbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    mapview.addSubview(Userbutton)

    mapview.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "H:[v0]-10-|", views: Userbutton)
    mapview.addConstraintsWithFormat(format: "V:[v0]-70-|", views: Userbutton)
```

Comment: Show your code that you are having issues with.

Comment: I already edited the question and added code. thanks. Any ideas?

Comment: The problem is that sometimes when the button is tapped the view will zoom out and centre on the user's current location but sometimes it just centres without zooming out. The behaviour that I want is for it to always  centre without zooming out

Answer (score 0):

> Does the MKUserTrackingButton have a property that I can alter so that when it is tapped, it only centres the map instead of zooming out?

No, when MKUserTrackingButton is tapped, it may or may not change the zoom level of the map depending on factors such as distance from the user's location.

> Is there a way to do that?

You could use Core Location to get the user's location and then set the center coordinate of the map directly without changing its zoom level.

Or simpler yet, if your map is already showing the user's location, you can get its coordinate from the `userLocation` property of the map.